# How to embed (insert object) documents in excel using phpexcel library?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I can manually embed a document **(insert -> object -> create from file)** using MS Excel. Please refer the image.

https://thewindowsclub-thewindowsclubco.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/select-format-option.png

How can I achieve this through PHPExcel or any other PHP library?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using phpspreadsheet, phpexcel has been replaced by it. I found this code in /templates/sampleSpreadsheet.php a subdirectory of my phpspreadsheet installation. You would likely find it in you phpexcel installation?

```
    // Add a drawing to the worksheet
$helper->log('Add a drawing to the worksheet');
$drawing = new Drawing();
$drawing->setName('PhpSpreadsheet logo');
$drawing->setDescription('PhpSpreadsheet logo');
$drawing->setPath(__DIR__ . '/images/PhpSpreadsheet_logo.png');
$drawing->setHeight(36);
$drawing->setCoordinates('D24');
$drawing->setOffsetX(10);
$drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
```